# Converted Drupal to WordPress: Network Error when trying to save changes

Tags: wordpress

The site is working except that any attempt to change content (i.e., update a contact) results in

Network Error
Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

I've verified that the database id/password is correct and has all privs.

I don't see anyplace where the old URLs might be.

Is there a way to debug this?

I've been through over a dozen similar question/answers without finding a solution.

Comment: Is the inspector console blank for errors?  I have had paths for extensions cause this. Even after updating paths and directories. If you have not already I would clear caches and templates_c directories

Comment: I usually use overrides to get the directories and urls working on conversions https://develop.tadpole.cc/snippets/20

Comment: We should probably change that "Network Error" message - to something more useful. It more often than not refers to a fatal/PHP error. Refreshing and trying again is not going to fix these.

Answer (score 1):

Dammit!  The views code in the database saves the userid for the query, which changed when I moved things. There's a WordPress plugin that can fix it, though I exported the database and did a search/replace to change the old user to the correct one.